# Adding column to table and then setting value gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am pretty new to SQL. I am working with SQL Server 2012. I need to do the following: add a column to an existing table and fill all rows in that column with the same value. To do this, I have come up with the following based on searching online:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(50) NULL
UPDATE myTable SET myNewColumn = 'test'
```

The problem is that in SQL server, I get the following error for the second statement:

> Invalid column name 'myNewColumn

So, my guess is that a new column called `myNewColumn` wasn't created by the first statement.

Comment: You need to use GO after each statement

Answer (score 8):

You need to perform the update in a separate batch. Otherwise SQL Server tries to parse and validate that the column exists before ever trying to run the `ALTER` that creates it. You get the invalid column name at parse time, not at run time.

One workaround is to use `GO` between the two batches:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(50) NULL;
GO
UPDATE dbo.myTable SET myNewColumn = 'test';
```

([Always use schema prefixes to reference objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and [always terminate statements with semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).)

However this only works in Management Studio and other certain client applications, because it is not actually part of the T-SQL language; these client tools see it as a batch separator and it tells them to submit and evaluate these two batches separately. It will NOT work in code blocks submitted to SQL Server in other ways and as a single batch, e.g. in the body of a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT 1;
  GO
  SELECT 2;
END
GO
```

This yields the following errors, because it actually splits the stored procedure into two separate batches:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure foo, Line 8
>   
> Incorrect syntax near ';'.
>   
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   
> Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

What you can do as a different workaround is force the update into its own batch by executing it in dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @value VARCHAR(50) = 'test';

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(50) NULL;

SET @sql = N'UPDATE dbo.myTable SET myNewColumn = @value;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@value VARCHAR(50)', @value;
```

([Why you should use `EXEC sp_executesql` vs. `EXEC(@sql)`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).)

Another workaround; perform the add and the update in one step:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'test' WITH VALUES;
```

(You can later drop the default constraint if you don't actually want any future rows to inherit that value in circumstances that would cause that behavior.)

Comment: And if they are on Enterprise Edition the "With Values" suggestion would be metadata only in 2012.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, true, thanks for bringing up that enhancement. Remus deep dove on that one here: http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/

Answer (score 4):

Place the word `GO` after your alter statement

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT("Something")
```

The problem with your code is that the column does not exist until after the query completes. So you can reference it until then.

Answer (score 0):

`Alter` and `update` cannot be executed at the same time. You need to segregate it using a built-in stored procedure to execute the update statement as under:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(50) NULL

Exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE myTable SET myNewColumn = ''test'''
```

This should definitely solve this problem.